# How to check a string includes a value or not in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

We have a string comparison like below.

```
value1 = "తెలుగు భాష {er}"
value2 = "తెలుగు భాష errr"
```

[image]
I have to check value 2 is same like value1 except for the err part.

```
  var separators = ['{er}','{Er}','{ER}','{#eR#}'];
    let dMsg = value1.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'),'g'));
    let msg = true;
    for (var m = 0; m < dMsg.length; m++) {
        if (!value1.includes(dMsg[m])) {
            Status = "Fail"
            break;
        }
    }
```

Even though both strings are same, Im getting status as failure. Can anybody help me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You are checking if `value1` includes characters from `value1`. Is this the correct behaviour?
And where is the `Status` variable defined?

Comment: It is defined at the top, I have not included here. Could you please suggest what should be the way?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is not giving me Fail message.

dMsg will be an array as split function return an array of strings.

In your case, `dMsg=['తెలుగు భాష ','']`

you should do `dMsg=dMsg[0]` before the loop starts.
This should resolve your issue.

Comment: There can be many {er} values,  that's why I'm checking with includes after splitting. For me , it is false. Please suggest

Comment: తెలుగు భాష please try with this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification, but "తెలుగు భాష" there seems to be something in between the above string, still it is not working, attaching the screenshot for your reference.

Comment: It would be ofgreat help, if you could look at the screenshot attached in the question

Comment: what you have in the screenshot seems to be a decimal point. It would be better if you make changes to the link above so i can see and experiment in order to help you.